# Ansible is not picking the group_vars and host_vars

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and couldn't figure out why the playbook is not picking up the group_vars/ and host_vars I have defined.  According to the document:

> You can also add group_vars/ and host_vars/ directories to your playbook directory. The ansible-playbook command looks for these directories in the current working directory by default.

My playbook, inventory, and other files structure are quite simple.  It should be matching the default.

[image]

Inventory file:

```
dummy

[spider]
s0ra
s0ra_slave
```

The playbook:

```yaml
- name: base mix release upgrade Prod.
  hosts: spider
  gather_facts: false

  # vars_files:
  # - vars/s0ra_sup.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: check release bin
      stat:
        path: "{{ sh_lastrel }}"
      register: rel_bin
```

When I tried to run the playbook by `ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini mix_upgrade.yaml`, it complains:

```sh
PLAY [base mix release upgrade Prod.] **********************************************************************************

TASK [check release bin] ***********************************************************************************************
fatal: [s0ra]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
The error was: 'sh_lastrel' is undefined\n\n
The error appears to be in 'xxx/ansible/mix_upgrade.yaml': line 19, column 7, but may\n
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n
The offending line appears to be:\n\n\n
    - name: check release bin\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
s0ra                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But the `sh_lastrel` is defined in `spider.yaml` actually.  I don't know why it is not loaded.  I tried to turn on -v mode but it does not seem to have more debugging info.  Any hint of the cause or how to further debug is greatly appreciated.

My ansible version is as below:

```
╰─ ansible --version                                                                                   ✔  22:01:57 
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/kenchen/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/kenchen/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/kenchen/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.2 (default, May 18 2020, 00:02:00) [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)]
```

Comment: This should be working. Make sure `group_vars/spider.yml` is readable by the user running the command. Post the file. Generally, make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It appear from your screenshot that you have a space in `group_ vars` -- that's a **fantastic** reason why one should not use code screenshots in questions, as is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: @mdaniel I am sorry that I was thinking that the coloring would help people easier to see the structure instead of some self-generated folder tree.  And you are right that the extra space broke it.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `group_vars/spider.yml` is available. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/spider.yml 
sh_lastrel: value of sh_lastrel defined in group_vars/spider.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory.ini
dummy
[spider]
s0ra
s0ra_slave
```

```yaml
shell> cat mix_upgrade.yaml 
- hosts: spider
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: sh_lastrel
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini mix_upgrade.yaml 

ok: [s0ra] => 
  sh_lastrel: value of sh_lastrel defined in group_vars/spider.yml
ok: [s0ra_slave] => 
  sh_lastrel: value of sh_lastrel defined in group_vars/spider.yml
```